# MVC Mapping - RedirectToAction not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC Project witch the default Mapping whcih I changed to:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{id}/{action}/{arg}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                      id = UrlParameter.Optional, arg = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

following Controllers:

**/Controllers/HomeController.cs:**

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{        
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "EPOS");
}
```

**/Controllers/EPOSController.cs:**

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    return View();
}
```

A breakpoint is being hit in the HomeController but isn't hit in the `EPOSController`, I get this error:

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What URL is generated for: return RedirectToAction("Index", "EPOS");

Comment: The URL remains the same when the error is shown in the browser `http://localhost:1096/`

Comment: Try using `RedirectToAction("Index", "EPOS", null);`.  Let me know if that changes the outcome.

Comment: @Shark Gives me the same error :(

Comment: Take a look at this post http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is because your `Default` route isn't correct:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{id}/{action}/{arg}", 
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",  
                      id = UrlParameter.Optional, arg = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
```

You can't have an optional parameter preceeding a required parameter.  What happens if you change the above route to this?

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{arg}", 
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",  
                      id = UrlParameter.Optional, arg = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
```

Comment: Your suggestion will not work either. It's not wrong, it's just a bug that was introduced in MVC 3. Take a look at this post by Phil Haack. http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/12/asp-net-mvc-2-optional-url-parameters.aspx

Comment: @epignosisx its about mvc2 not mvc3

Comment: @Shark sorry I gave you the wrong link. this is the one: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think Shark is right, try splitting your Route Map into two definitions something like this (I have not tested this)

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{id}/{action}/{arg}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                  arg = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                  id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```